# Route Base Nuxt not working as I expected

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a question about router base
for example I have a nuxt project with pages like this :

> - pages
>
>   - a
>
>     - index.vue
>   - b
>
>     - index.vue

I made a router base = '/a/', so when I run the project, the URL will directly go to base router, https://localhost:3000/a

It didn't show the index.vue on pages a. I should use the URL https://localhost:3000/a/a to show the index.vue on pages a.

My question is, is it normally like that ? Or there is any other way to use URL https://localhost:3000/a to directly open index.vue on pages a ?

Comment: The base, is basically what you have between `https://mywebsite.com` and any path like `/our-team`. So, if you have base as `'a'`, it will behave like `https://mywebsite.com/a/our-team` indeed. What do you want to achieve here? That `/` forwards to `/a` with an alias?

Comment: I understand now about the base.

What I want to achieve in here is I want my nuxt project to make a/index.vue as root
So when I want to access a file in static, it will be opened like this localhost:3000/a/sitemap.xml

Comment: I've posted an answer, did you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried, but I found another way with router middleware. thank you for the answer

Comment: Does it work if you have your initial render? Middlewares are aimed to be used with client-side navigation. Double check that it's fine SEO-wise + on initial render.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a middleware runs everytime so it may take some resources on each navigation, don't put too much logic in it!

Comment: what do you mean by initial render ? is it ssr ?

Comment: The first time your arrive on your app is called "initial render". Then, you have your SPA and you can move freely thanks to Vue-router. If I'm not mistaken, a middleware will only run during client-side navigations. But if you put it on your whole app (`nuxt.config.js`, `router` key), it may work globally even for the initial render. Not sure, didn't used that for some time already.

Comment: I see
Yes I put it on global (nuxt.config.js, router.middleware)

Comment: Nvm, not sure what I'm telling right now. A middleware works even on the initial render. Sorry for that haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246668/discussion-between-restu-and-kissu).

Comment: Thanks for the help :D

anyway, I have another question about router middleware.
What I know about it is, it only work while I hit nuxt-link (vue-router) and it won't work while I write the URL manually on address bar or while I refresh the page

Am I right ?
Also, do you have any suggestion about it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install and setup this package: https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module

---

Then, you can have the content of the page `a` on `/` with the following

`/pages/a.vue`

```html
<router>
{
  alias: '/'
}
</router>

<template>
  <div>Content page A</div>
</template>
```

No need for a `/pages/index.vue` in this case btw.

---

Or you can have a redirect and see the content of page `a` on `/a` with the following

`/pages/index.vue`

```html
<router>
{
  redirect: '/a'
}
</router>
```

`/pages/a.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>Content page A</div>
</template>
```

PS: since this is related to router configuration, keep in mind that a server restart may be mandatory to take the updates into account.